# How to make primary constructor parameters readonly?

Tags: c#

I am trying to familiarize with the C# 12 primary constructor variables.

Here is my code:

```
public class BankAccountNew(string accountID, string owner)
{
    public void DoSomethingWrong()
    {
        accountID = "Wrong";
    }

}

public class BankAccounOld
{
    private readonly string accountID;
    private readonly string owner;

    public BankAccounOld(string accountID, string owner)
    {
        this.accountID = accountID;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWrong()
    {
        accountID = "Wrong";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want `DoSomethingWrong` cause a compiler error to be triggered as it modifies a parameter I want to be readonly. I succeed in this for `BankAccounOld` but this requires me to type a lot of code which is not needed anymore in the latest C# version.

As explained `accountID` is supposed to be readonly. How do I change `BankAccountNew` to ensure this is recognized as readonly so it triggers a compiler error?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. From the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors): "Primary constructor parameters can be assigned to." - hence, they cannot be readonly. They're also not members of the class.

Comment: What's the *actual* problem you want to solve? Primary constructors aren't an alternative to `record`. First of all, these are private fields, not properties. Child classes won't see them. The compiler won't even emit them unless they're used in the class itself. When you write `accountID = "Wrong";` you're explicitly telling the compiler you *want* to keep that field. Had you used `readonly string MyAccountID= accountID;` the `accountID` field wouldn't even get generated.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `record` is fine if the goal is to expose public immutable properties, but often we want classes that have private immutable fields (e.g. a service class with injected dependencies that shouldn't change over the lifetime of the object). This is a perfectly legitimate scenario for which `record` is not appropriate. F# for example treats primary constructor parameters as immutable, which is a safer default.

Answer (score 10):

Panagiotis Kanavos mentioned it in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044906/how-to-make-primary-constructor-parameters-readonly#comment135821226_77044906) already, there is an intermediate solution that correctly triggers a compiler error. In the following example, no field `accountID` is generated, but its value is assigned to `myAccountID` on instantiation.

```cs
public class BankAccoun(string accountID, string owner)
{
    private readonly string myAccountID = accountID;
    private readonly string myOwner = owner;

    public void DoSomethingWrong()
    {
        myAccountID = "Wrong";
    }
}
```

The caveat here is, that the field `accountID` gets generated and can be changed, in case it is ever accessed in the class. E.g. if you change the method to:

```cs
public void DoSomethingWrong()
{
    accountID = "Wrong";
}
```

You can prevent that by naming your readonly field the same as your constructor parameter. According to [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGED2AbbEDGMAlpgHYAyRMECU2yANACYgDUAPgAIDMABJwCZeAISikA1gEF8+THFIAKTgEYADLygy5pGAEkAIg35remAO6kaASgCwAKADe93i94AHBEQBusCLyRQTGTYAJ7G6pqy8nr6vAC8GlrRBgDczq4e3r7+0EGkoeGmFjTxRZYIaXbpLjz8ACy8+pgAypgAthAwABZEpADmAOoIZH0KtnauvE4Tk66R2jGlAERDI0uVkwC+9ptAA===) the following works as you requested:

```cs
public class BankAccoun(string accountID, string owner)
{
    private readonly string accountID = accountID;
    private readonly string owner = owner;

    public void DoSomethingWrong()
    {
        accountID = "Wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is useful but it solves another problem. It shows how to add extra parameters with different names. That is very important. But it answers a different question.

Comment: @Daan Well, the second example I gave does fulfill your requirements. It has a primary constructor and readonly fields. Yes, it is more typing than if there was a readonly modifier in the constructor or something, but it is still 50 characters less typing, than if you would do it the old way.

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be a way by declaring the parameter as 'in' in the primary ctor. The following code snippet works:

```
    public class SomeClass(in int param)
    {
        private readonly int _param = param;
        public int GetSum(int other)
        {
            // Cannot access 'param' here.
            return other + _param;
        }
    }
```

The primary ctor parameter is now not available in the method but only in the initialization of the private readonly field making it effectively readonly.

EDIT: Writing '++param' in the assignment leads to a compiler error, therefore if is actually really read-only.

Answer (score 3):

Primary constructors are new and there are still some limitations.

Making them `readonly` is currently not possible but should hopefully come soon.

This video from Nick Chapsas explains in well, and he looks into the IL code as well.

https://youtu.be/hcCT5J-SKEA?si=Ka-W7Cxp-dVABTRn&t=240

Comment: This isn't a *limitation*. Primary constructors aren't records. They do one job and that's not defining readonly properties or fields

Comment: BTW you can use sharplab.io to see what's actually generated as C#. No need for IL

Comment: I often make my private fields readonly. Currently, if I want to have it as readonly, I have to assign the primary constructor parameter to an explicitly declared readonly field. I hope they will add the `readonly` modifier not only in primary constructors but also for method parameters. Note that in records the primary constructor parameters generate public properties. You may not want it to be public and you may not want it to be a property.

Comment: The main issue currently is that IDEs will suggest that you use a primary constructor to replace readonly fields. The primary constructor feature in itself is fine.

Answer (score 1):

With C# 12, if you create a class with Primary Constructors, the parameters will not have the `readonly` restriction, and there is no way to add it.

The only way is with a `readonly struct` (or a record).

> In a readonly struct the capture fields will be readonly. Therefore, access to captured parameters of a readonly struct will have similar restrictions as access to readonly fields. Access to captured parameters within a readonly member will have similar restrictions as access to instance fields in the same context.
>
> [MS Docs, C# 12 Features, Primary constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors#semantics)

[This code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGED2AbbEDGMAlpgHYAyRMECU2yAPgAIBMAjALABQTAzAARIoAEzLYAnv2QwEcQv3QAKIqRj8oAGn4q1wAJT8A3t36n+ABwREAbrAj8mAFn4AxTJkUHDDtgE5FUHoA3PwAvtyhQA)...

```
public readonly struct C(int a) {
    private void Foo() { Console.WriteLine(a); }
}
```

would prevent the modification of the `a` variable.

Unfortunately, you're out of luck right now for classes. Consider using a record instead.

Comment: That's because the type is `readonly`, not because of special treatment of structs. The readonly equivalent for classes is `record`