# С# 12, primary constructors

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, c#-12.0

In new version of C# (v.12) there are primary constructors, so, we can write:

```
public interface IService
{
    Distance GetDistance();
}

public class ExampleController(IService service) : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IService _service = service;
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Distance> Get()
    {
        return _service.GetDistance();
    }
}
```

or even this

```
public class ExampleController(IService service) : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<Distance> Get()
    {
        return service.GetDistance();
    }
}
```

second option even more comfortable to use (and shorter)
But, is it good way (option #1) or possible is better to use option #1? Because theoretically, we can change `service` variable with unexpected behavior directly in the code.

Comment: What do you mean a "good way"? It clearly is *possible* because the code compiles. This sounds primarily opinion based.

Comment: Basically, you're asking how you can use the second style of C# 12 primary-ctor `class` such that the compiler generates a `readonly` fields (or property) - the answer currently is "**you can't**". [See the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044906/how-to-make-primary-constructor-parameters-readonly).